# Show a bottomsheet on ChangeNotifier notifyListeners in Flutter

Tags: flutter

In my ChangeNotifier model, I have a variable called leveledUpLevel. On change of this variable, I want to show a bottomsheet on a couple of pages based on what's visible at that time. I tried two approaches.

**Triggering change in Model Class**

```
 void notifyLevelUp(int? level) {
    leveledUpLevel = level;
    if (level != null) {
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }
```

**Approach 1 inside the Widget**

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Consumer<Model>(
      builder: (context, model, child) {
if(model.leveledUpLevel != null){
showBottomSheet();
....
```

**Approach 2 inside the Widget**

```
Model? _appModel;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  
    _model = context.read<Model>();
    _model?.addListener(levelUp);
  }

  levelUp() {
    if (_model != null &&
        _model !.leveledUpLevel != null) {
     showBottomSheet();
    }
  }
```

None of the approaches work. The first one crashes the second one could show the bottom sheet multiple times if `notifyListeners` is called by some other events.

What is the correct way to do this using `ChangeNotifierProvider`? Do I have to create a dedicated ValueNotifier event in my model for this and trigger it instead?

Comment: wouldnt calling showBottomSheet in notifyLevelUp solve your problem?

Comment: It's in the model class, showBottomSheet is called inside a widget/page